# Prove $ |A \cup B| = |[0,1]| \Rightarrow |A|=|[0,1]| \bigvee |B|=|[0,1]| $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I've tried the argument by contradiction, but did not succeed.

Intuitively I understand that union of less-than-continuum sets cannot equal to $|\mathbb{R}|$. I'm curious what a formal proof could be.

Comment: The argument goes by contradiction. Try assuming that $A$ and $B$ are countable. What do we observe for the union?

Comment: @M.Winter Careful not to assume the continuum hypothesis

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Right, thank you. This only works assuming CH.

Comment: A proof without CH can utilize the following lemma: let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Then the cardinality of the finite union of a collection of sets all of cardinality $\leq \kappa$ is $\leq \kappa$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979027/cardinality-of-the-union-of-two-infinite-set). Also, one answer includes that $\kappa+\kappa=\kappa$ for an infinite cardinal $\kappa$. It is using the axiom of choice.

Comment: Thank you, @M.Winter. I will try your way after I learn more about cardinals.

Comment: @M.Winter: And choice is essential.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Or CH?

Comment: @skyking: If you're formalizing CH as $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, this is a choice-assumption. If you're formalizing it as "no intermediate cardinals", then you're reduced back to the countable case indeed, which I have mentioned in my answer. But in either case you're falling under the parenthetical remark I made about technical set theoretic concepts.

Answer (score 2):

There is no naive proof.

More specifically, any proof is going to have to rely on the following property of infinite cardinals: $$\kappa+\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}.$$
This property follows from the axiom of choice (and as stated here is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice). So some nontrivial work is needed.

Why is it needed? Well, it turns out that it is consistent without the axiom of choice that there are $A,B\subseteq[0,1]$ such that $A\cup B=[0,1]$, but both $A$ and $B$ have cardinality less than the continuum. This is due to G. P. Monro.

> *Monro, G.P.*, [**Decomposable cardinals**](https://eudml.org/doc/214599), Fundam. Math. 80, 101-104 (1973). [ZBL0272.02085](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0272.02085).

The most you can prove naively without choice, is that if $A$ is countable, then $|B|=|[0,1]|$. (You can say more, of course, but that would require getting your hands dirty in technical concepts of set theory.)

---

Assuming the aforementioned property of infinite cardinals, the proof is nearly trivial. $|A\cup B|=\max\{|A|,|B|\}$. So if that would be $|[0,1]|$, it has to be that one of $A$ or $B$ has the same cardinality.